# How to capture Google Maps API CENTER_CHANGED events on iPad web browser?

Tags: ipad, google-maps

Messages such as CENTER_CHANGED on a web Browser HTML based google map get fired ok on desktop PC or laptop web browsers but on iPhones and iPads they never return the correct center coordinates when fored. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.
not only for `center_changed`, but also `drag`, `mousemove` events, they all does not update bounds and center of the current map. it only updates when the move is done.

You can go around this in some complex way like this,

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function(event) {
      //save drag start bounds
      //save mouse starting point
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(event) {
      //get mouse moving distance
      //calculate center from start bounds and mouse moving distance
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragEnd', function(event) {
      //save drag end bounds
    });
```

I don't know your purpose of this. However, if it is to show markers dynamically, I would load all markers of 9 windows, which is the maximum of your center changing limit.

```
+--------+--------+--------+
:        :        :        :
:        :        :        :
+--------+========+--------+
:        | view   |        :
:        | port   |        :
+--------+========+--------+
:        :        :        :
:        :        :        :
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: The reason I needed it was to view details of the marker at the center of the map dynamically. I had a demo up at onthemap.at, but thanks, I just needed confirmation that this is not possible. I have to admit I could not figure out how to calculate the distance for the mouse